# Rails - annotate PDF in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, annotations

In my (very first) rails app, I have a model called "Annotations"; this will take some generic data as well as an attachment (PDF). Next, I need to the ability to do the actual annotations to this attachment/PDF ("annotate") and store the results on a field on the "Annotations" model (as a JSON?).

Currently, I think I should create a new method "annotate" in the AnnotationsController (needs to update the annotations object) and call a new view called "`annotate.html.erb`".

Any advice how to go about "the rails way" ?

**Update**
meanwhile, I have:

**model** (`annotation.rb`)

```
class Annotation < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :documenttype
    has_attached_file :file, styles: { large: "600x600>", medium: "500x500>", thumb: "150x150#" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :documenttype

    validates_attachment_content_type :file, content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'application/pdf']

    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 50 }
    validates :description, length: { minimum: 20, maximum: 500 }
    validates :documenttype, presence: true
    validates :file, presence: true
end
```

**routes**

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
      root 'dashboard#index'
      devise_for :users
      resources :users,:documenttypes, :documents
      resources :annotations do
        resources :comments
  end
  get "annotate", to: "annotations#annotate"
```

the **controller** (AnnotationsController)

```
class AnnotationsController < ApplicationController
before_action :annotate, only: [:edit, :update ]

def index
    @annotations = Annotation.all
end

def show
    @annotation = Annotation.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @annotation = Annotation.new
end

def edit
    @annotation = Annotation.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @annotation = Annotation.new(annotation_params)

    if @annotation.save
        redirect_to @annotation
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def update
    @annotation = Annotation.find(params[:id])

    if @annotation.update(annotation_params)
        redirect_to @annotation
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @annotation = Annotation.find(params[:id])
    @annotation.destroy

    redirect_to annotations_path
end

private

    def annotate
        @annotation = Annotation.find(params[:id])
    end

    def annotation_params
        params.require(:annotation).permit(:name, :description, :file, :active, :documenttype_id)
    end
end
```

**views** that render 1 form (using simple_form)

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
    <h4>Annotation</h4>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= simple_form_for @annotation,  html: { class: 'form-horizontal', multipart: true },
        wrapper: :horizontal_form,
        wrapper_mappings: {
            check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
            radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
            file: :horizontal_file_input,
            boolean: :horizontal_boolean
          } do |f| %>

          <%= f.error_notification %>

          <% if @annotation.file.blank? %>
            <%= f.input :file, as: :file, input_html: { accept: ('application/pdf') } %>
            <% else %>
          <% end -%>

            <%= f.input :name, placeholder: 'Enter name' %>

            <%= f.input :description, placeholder: 'Description' %>

            <%= f.association :documenttype %>

          <%= f.input :active, as: :boolean %>

          <%= f.button :submit %>
          <% unless @annotation.file.blank? %>
          <%= link_to ' Annotate', annotate_path(@annotation), :class => "btn btn-default" %>
          <% end -%>

      <% end -%>

      <p><br><%= link_to 'List' , annotations_path %></p>

    </div>

    <% unless @annotation.file.blank? %>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p><strong>File name: </strong><%= @annotation.file_file_name %></p>
      <iframe src="<%= @annotation.file %>" width=100% height=450px class="img-rounded"></iframe>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <% unless @annotation.new_record? %>
  <div class="row">
    <hr>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= render @annotation.comments %>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= render 'comments/form' %>
      </div>

  </div>
  <% end -%>

</div>
```

Also, I created a view call `annotate.html.erb`

It is called now as static page under `http://localhost:3000/annotate` ; while I think it should be under `http://localhost:3000/annotations/annotate/:id` -- so looks like a routing issue (for) now. (Routing still is a bit of a mystery to me :-) )

Comment: Just curious how did this work out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the routing `get "annotations/:id/annotate" => "annotations#annotate", as: 'annotate'`

And the `set_annotation` method should not be private.

May be there is a better routing (always welcome), but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it the `rails` way:

Your model should be singular, so: `Annotation.rb`:

```
class Annotation < ApplicationRecord

end
```

Your controller should be called `AnnotationsController` and have the standard CRUD methods: `new` and `create` (to create a new annotation). `edit` and `update` to update an annotation and `destroy` to destroy your annotations.

SOMETHING LIKE:

```
class AnnotationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_annotation, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @annotations = Annotation.all
  end

  def new
    @annotation = Annotation.new
  end

  def create
    @annotation = Annotation.new(annotation_params)

    if @annotation.save
      redirect_to annotations_path, notice: "annotations created"
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
    @annotation.destroy
    redirect_to annotations_path
  end

  def update
    if @annotation.update(annotation_params)
      redirect_to annotations_path
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def set_annotation
    @annotation = Annotation.find(params[:id])
  end

  def annotation_params
    params.require(:annotation).permit(:name, ...)
  end
end
```

Your views should live in `views/annotations/`

Since this is your first rails app, I suggest you use the scaffolding option to build your app, which according to the documetation is:

> A scaffold in Rails is a full set of model, database migration for
>   that model, controller to manipulate it, views to view and manipulate
>   the data, and a test suite for each of the above.

`rails g scaffold Annotate`

see: `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html`

Comment: Have that done - followed the get started guide to do so. Next, after the an annotation is created, is to add this function to actually annotate the PDF.

What in your view does set_annotation do? It is the same as a show - right? And why is it a private method?

Doing this results in routing error - no routes matches [post] "/annotations/7"

Comment: In order to give any comment, you would need to show us what you have done so far. Some code would help.

Comment: In your `routes`, change `resources :annotations do` to be just: `resources :annotations`. Equally, to get an idea of your current routes, in your command line, run: `rake routes`, this will also give you the URI pattern that's being matched

Comment: when I remove the do, I get an error - resources: comments is nested.

Comment: You are right, I didn't see the `end`. So if your question is related to routing, I would take a look at the output of the command I pasted above and see how that helps you.

Comment: did that give only GET    /annotate(.:format) with controller#action as annotations#annotate. So how do I change the routing to make an edit? Or should a take a different approach - add a section to the _form in which the annotation is done? Which ever is simpler.

Comment: What `resources` does is create resourceful routing for you. `rake routes` gives you the output of that. The `edit` route created will mean you have a path at: `/annotations/:id/edit` - the view should live in: `views/annotations/edit.html.erb`.

Comment: Yep, I have that. Now I have a special case - I need this annotate page to edit 1 specific field of the record. Doable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122826/discussion-between-christian-g-and-dimitri-de-ruiter).